# Nest.js can't resolve the dependencies of CacheConfigService

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, nestjs

I want to use the CacheModule in the AuthModule and I have written this code but still getting the error in the console:
[image]

The Auth.module.ts file in which I want to import the cache module:

```
@Module({
  providers: [CacheConfigService, SupertokensService],
  exports: [],
  imports: [CacheConfigModule, UsersModule],
  controllers: [],
})
export class AuthModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }

  static forRoot({
    connectionURI,
    apiKey,
    appInfo,
  }: AuthModuleConfig): DynamicModule {
    return {
      // providers and exports
      imports: [CacheConfigModule],
    };
  }
}
```

The cache config.module.ts file code. The cache config.service.ts file contains the logic:

```
@Module({
  providers: [CacheConfigService],
  exports: [CacheConfigService],
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register<RedisClientOptions>({
      isGlobal: true,
      // store: redisStore,
      url: 'redis://' + process.env.REDIS_HOST + ':' + process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    }),
  ],
})
export class CacheConfigModule {}
```

I want to use the cache service in the following class:

```
@Injectable()
export class SupertokensService {
  private redisClient = redis.createClient({
    url: this.cacheConfigService.url,
  });

  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UsersService)) private userService: UsersService,
    private cacheConfigService: CacheConfigService
  ) {
    supertokens.init({
      appInfo: this.config.appInfo,
      supertokens: {
        connectionURI: this.config.connectionURI,
        apiKey: this.config.apiKey,
      },
      recipeList: [
        ThirdPartyEmailPassword.init({
          providers: [
            ThirdPartyEmailPassword.Google({
              clientSecret: 'TODO: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET',
              clientId:
                'CLIENT_ID',
            }),
          ],
          signUpFeature: {
            ...signup logic
          },
          override: {
            apis: (originalImplementation: any) => {
              return {
                ...originalImplementation,

                emailPasswordSignInPOST: async (input: any) => {
                  if (
                    originalImplementation.emailPasswordSignInPOST === undefined
                  ) {
                    throw Error('Should never come here');
                  }

                  let response: any =
                    await originalImplementation.emailPasswordSignInPOST(input);

                  // retrieving the input from body logic
                  const { email } = inputObject;
                  const user = await this.userService.findOneByEmail(email);
                  const id = user?.id;
                  const token = jwt.sign({email, id}, 'mysecret';, {
                    expiresIn: '2h',
                  });
                  response.token = token;
                  await this.redisClient.set("Token", token, {
                    EX: 60 * 60 * 24,
                  });
                  return response;
                },
              };
            },
          },
        }),
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error has been thrown because you have used `ConfigService` in `CacheConfigService`, but it has never been imported into `CacheConfigModule`.

If you want to have `ConfigService` then you must import it into `AppModule`, as well as `CacheConfigModule`.

**app.module.ts**:

```js
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import configuration from './config/configuration'; // or wherever your config file exists

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
    }),
    // rest of code
  ],
  // rest of code
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**config.module.ts**:

```js
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  providers: [CacheConfigService],
  exports: [CacheConfigService],
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register<RedisClientOptions>({
      isGlobal: true,
      // store: redisStore,
      url: 'redis://' + process.env.REDIS_HOST + ':' + process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    }),
    ConfigModule,
  ],
})
export class CacheConfigModule {}
```

Comment: To add to this, you can also set `isGlobal: true` in the `ConfigModule.forRoot()` options and not have to worry about importing the `ConfigModule` anywhere else